# Join and map 2 RDDs conditionally

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 RDDs which need to be joined

```
val rdd1 = RDD[(v_id, inputObject1)]
```

where v_id is unique id

and inputObject1 has following fields

```
g_id, p_id, timestamp=t1
```

Now i have another RDD

```
val rdd2 = RDD[(g_id, inputObject2)]
```

where inputObject2 has following fields

```
p_id, timestamp=t2, e_id
```

Now i want to join these 2 RDDs on below condition

- If g_id and p_id is same and |t1-t2| < 30 minutes
- Else if g_id is same and |t1 - t2| < 30 minutes

So second condition is fallback if first condition is not met. My final output should be this

```
val resuldRDD = RDD[(v_id, inputObject11)]
```

Where inputObject11 = inputObject1 + adding e_id from second RDD if conditions are met.

So fields will be

```
g_id, p_id, e_id, timestamp=t1
```

Comment: nor sure you can join with conditions. You can join by id, and then filter based on whatever condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* possible:  the `join` operations are ***by key***

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

[image]